# What will be the correct java application type as per my need?

Tags: java, web-applications, desktop-application, java-web-start

I want to create an application upon `Java` technology which can be any of them:

1. A standalone desktop application on Swing,
2. A webstart application,
3. A web application deployed on Apache Tomcat or Google App Engine.

Coming back to type and nature of application, it is a Network based application say such as a `Retail Application` based on three layers say `Employee`, `Manager` and `Administrator`.

Now things which are sure:

1. `Administrator` will be single for whole application.
2. `Managers` are appointed for every branch (or say for every store).
3. Every branch/store will have 4-5 `Employees`.
4. Respective `Manager` and `Employees` will be connected via LAN.
5. Every branch's `Manager` will be connected to the `Administrator` or vice versa.
6. The `Administrator` application will be a web-based app, that can be accessed by admin any where.

Now my confusion is with `Employee` and `Manager` consoles, I want to have only *one application* that can be accessed by both employee and manager as per authentication, as they are on same branch but I am confused with the *type* of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any type of application could be used in any of the roles.

You need to understand the pros and cons of each approach, and make your own choices.  Ultimately, it boils down to a question of whether you want to have to install Java and / or a Java application on the users' PCs.

- A purely web-based UI requires no Java installation, but it means that you will need to use technologies such as HTML, CSS and Javascript to implement much of the UI code.
- Swing requires you to install BOTH Java AND the application on the user's PC.  You also need to deal with getting the users to install updates.  On the other hand, you don't need to deal with browser incompatibilities and you can implement just in Java.
- WebStart requires you to install ONLY Java, and a tiny JNLP file.  Webstart takes care of downloading and caching the application from a central server, and deals with updates too.

---

No matter what you choose for your UI implementation, you also need some kind of backends to (at least) accept and process requests from the users, and manage the data / databases.  You could implement this using GAE or Tomcat or any number of alternatives.

Comment: thanks for the nice suggestions, i would re-look at my needs and then suggest myself the right way. . .but till now, _installation_ is not the issue in my application, the confusion is due to _security_ and _resource access_.

Comment: @Asit - ultimately, it doesn't make any difference from a security / resource access standpoint.  The issues exist (more or less) with all three choice.  None of the choices automatically solve them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to write a Java Web Start application using the NetBeans Platform (Swing based RCP):

http://netbeans.org/features/platform/

The desktop application then could access Web Services (Internet) or remote EJBs (LAN), which have been deployed to a Java EE application server such as GlassFish.

Comment: Yeah Web-start seems a good choice but i want to create application from scratch without any specific framework and actually I did not know much about Web-Start till now, can you please provide some useful link about web start and how can i access Web Resources (JSPs/ Servlets) through webstart application/